# ios - How to properly export videos using GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I can't seem to get the GPUImageMovieWriter to work properly.

Despite the fact that the authors are always suggesting to look over their examples; none of them are able to properly build and run.

So here's my code sample:

```
ALAsset *asset = (ALAsset *)[self galleryImages][indexPath.row];
NSURL *fileURLForInput = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL];

GPUImageMovie *movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:fileURLForInput];
movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;

NSURL *fileURLForOutput = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self getVideoLocalFilePathWithVideoID:videoID]];

GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:fileURLForOutput size:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;

[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    PSLog(@"DONE!");
}];
```

Running the code sample results in a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.[image]

And if I were to remove this line:

```
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];
```

The app does not crash but the output file has a size of 0 bytes and the completion block is never called.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[movieFile addTarget:movieWriter]` before you start processing the movie.

Comment: Hi David, It still didn't work. This was the error that i'm getting: http://i.imgur.com/8VQalbn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the GPUImageMovie and GPUImageMovieWriter variable a strong property or an instance variable.